# How to use Vue v-model binding in Vuetify components together with computed properties and Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use v-radio-group in conjunction with computed values from Vuex as described similarly [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html).

Example codepen of the issue I'm facing is [here](https://codepen.io/patchee500/pen/vYEJXQv?editors=1011)

Whenever a radio button is clicked, a Vuex mutation is called to save the selected value in the state.
However it can be the case that some validation fails inside the mutation and that therefore the value is not changed in the state as expected.

Regardless of what value ends up in the Vuex state, the radio buttons do not truly reflect the current state.

E.g. in the codepen snippet I'd expect the second option (`Option 1`) never to show as chosen, as the corresponding state is always 0.

As far as I can see this behavior is not only happening when using v-radio-groups.
It happens with all Vuetify components using `v-model` and computed getters/setters.
So e.g. Vuetifys v-text-input/v-text-field and v-select also show the same behavior.

To sum it up, my questions are the following:
Why is the second option in my codepen example getting selected even as the corresponding state is different?
How can I achieve the expected result (Having `Option 1` never shown as selected, even when it is clicked)?

Comment: You should not perform any validation inside of a mutation. It is a pure function intended for writing to the store. If you need to perform validation, actions are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Vuetify keeps its own state in their components like `v-radio-group`.

To change it you need to send updated props. Then it will react and update its own state.

The trouble is that you are performing validation in a mutation. Which is a bad practice in my opinion.

I will show you how to "block" changing state and update `v-radio-group` so its own state corresponds to what is actually  in your `$store.state.radioState`.

And I will spend some more time to figure out how to performe it in on mutation ;-)

**This is not a perfect solution** >> [my codepen](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/wvBqgRE?editors=1011)

1. Your mutation just updates the state.

```js
// store.js
mutations: {
  setRadioState (state, data) {
    state.radioState = data;
  },
},
```

2. Your `set` method do the validation.

```js
// component 
computed: {
  chosenOption: {
    get () { 
      return this.$store.state.radioState;
    },
    set (value) {
      if (value !== 1) {
       this.$store.commit('setRadioState', value) 
      } else {
        const oldValue = this.$store.state.radioState
        this.$store.commit('setRadioState', value)
        this.$nextTick(() => {
         this.$store.commit('setRadioState', oldValue)
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. What happens in the `set` when it fails validation? You save current state to `oldValue`, you update state so it corresponds to `v-radio-group` component. And in the `$nextTick` you change it right back to `oldValue`. That way `v-radio-group` gets updated props and change its state to yours.